# HTTP Status 404 in spring while submitting the form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication

i have a form which submits the value to a controller in spring.

this is what is my servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.anto.springsec.controllers" />

</beans:beans>
```

this is what web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and this is what is my controller :

```
package com.anto.springsec.controllers;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String printWelcome( ) {

        return "createContact";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model) {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "true");
        return "login";
    }

}
```

and this is what is my jsp file :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function login(){
    alert("login");
    document.forms[0].action="login";
    document.forms[0].method="post";
    document.forms[0].submit();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-2" action="login" method="post" >

    <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2" width="100%"><b>  <h1> <span class="log-in">Login</span></h1></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2" width="100%"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="float">
                <td align="right" class="icon-user" width="50%"><label for="login"><i class="icon-user"></i>Username</label> </td>
                <td align="left" class="field" width="50%"><input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Username "></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="float">
                <td align="right" class="icon-lock" width="50%"><label for="password"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Password</label></td>
                <td align="left" class="field" width="50%"><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="showpassword"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" colspan="2" width="50%"><input type="submit" name="CreateContact" value="Login" /><i class="icon-user"></i></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to redirect the control to login controller and get the username and password and redirect to some page.

but when i submit the request i get `404` exception,

since i am new to spring i am not able to figure out the problem, Please explain why it occurs.

```
EDIT :
```

this is from the server console :

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springsec/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Best Regards

Comment: any error/warnings in the sever log

Comment: hi Arun Edited the question, Please have a look at it

Comment: what is `springsec`? also the login page is displayed in the browser right, only post request is not working

Comment: project Name is springsec, Yes i get the login page i have to submit the form as you said post request is not submitted

Comment: Post to ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login

Comment: Which url shows the jsp you have above?

Comment: Can you change the to `document.forms[0].action="/springsec/login";` and try

Comment: Hi Varun Achar can you be littler understandable, where to put this line. please don't mind for this question since i am very new to spring

Comment: Can you confirm whether the alert `login` is appearing

Comment: Change `<form class="form-2" action="login" method="post" >` to <form class="form-2" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="post" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login`.. This will post to springsec/login

Right now the form is post to `/login`. `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` will add springsec to the path. Your application is accessible through `localhost:8080/springsec`

In your form use

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="post">
```

or if submitting by Js.

```
document.forms[0].action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login";
document.forms[0].method="post";
document.forms[0].submit();
```

NOTE : above will work only if they are written in a JSP file. Not in HTML or JS files

Comment: The WARN says otherwise: `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springsec/login]`, while his controller is mapped to `/login`

Comment: i have submitted the form using javascript, so how to use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login`

Comment: @Sotirios: Oh yeah.. sorry.. didn't see that.. 
@Anto : just use the line that i've posted.. it's a object available by default to in jsp.. The server will replace `${pageCon..` with the appropriate value automatically..

Comment: Also, try changing `@RequestMapping(value="/login")` to `@RequestMapping(value="login")` without the forward slash.. I think it's an absolute path issue

Answer (score 2):

In your JSP file, you need to add this at the beginning

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

You also need to use tags like `<form:form>`, `<form:input>` etc. Please check out [Spring MVC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html).

If you use html tag `<form>`, you have to add the context-root before your post URL like

```
<form class="form-2" action="/<your-context-root>/login" method="post" >
```

However, mostly likely you would need data-binding between your view and your backing beans. So I would recommend using `<form:form>`, `<form:input>`, which will figure out the context-root for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is really silly mistake i made, forgot to add `@Controller` which was casting me the hell.

Anyway thanks for all your contribution towards this question.